# Почему PDO::lastInsertId возвращает неверный ID при частых вставках в БД?

Tags: php, apache, yii, sql-server, pdo

Существует веб-приложение (Win7x64, MS Sql Server 2012, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6, Yii 1.1).
Около сотни пользователей постоянно наполняют одну таблицу. В случае, если разные пользователи в одно и тоже время произвели вставку строки, первому возвращается ID вставленной строки второго и дальнейшие действия, например сохранение истории изменений, ведется с неверным ID. 
Yii использует PDO, в частности метод lastInsertId для получения айдишника, но описания подобной проблемы в интернете не встретил.

Для чистоты эксперимента, я создал две новые таблица Collision и CollisionHistory:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Collision](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[uuid] [varchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Collision] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CollisionHistory](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[collision_id] [int] NULL,
[uuid] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CollisionHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
)
```

На их основе в gii генерю модели.
В модель Collision добавляю код:

```
public function afterSave(){
    parent::afterSave();
    $history = new CollisionHistory();
    $history->collision_id = $this->id;
    $history->uuid = $this->uuid;
    $history->save(false);
}
```

Пишу контроллер

```
class CollisionController extends CController
{

    public function actionTest()
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
            $model = new Collision();
            $model->uuid = $this->UUIDv4();
            $model->save(false);
        }
    }

    private function UUIDv4()
    {
        return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
            mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,
            mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
        );
    }

}
```

Затем на счет три с коллегой запускаем actionTest каждый со своего компьютера.
В итоге на 2000 инсертов  в таблицу Collision 419 повторений collision_id в таблице CollisionHistory.

Почему такое происходит и как этого избежать?

Comment: Для начала я бы провел тот же тест на чистом PDO. Чтобы аргументация была не "Yii использует PDO", а либо "В PDO косяк", либо "Yii неправильно использует PDO"

Comment: Провел тест чисто на PDO, результат повторился. думаю использовать для вставки хранимую процедуру со SCOPE_IDENTITY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Провел тест на чистом PDO, поменял несколько версий, но результат тот же.
Метод PDO::lastinsertid возвращает самый последний id для таблицы, как функция MSSQL IDENT_CURRENT()

То есть, если между вставкой и получением id произошла вставка в другой сессии, то возвращается id из второй сессии.

Свою проблему решил созданием хранимой процедуры для вставок в самую часто-используемую таблицу, в которой выходной параметр заполняется функцией SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Кстати, используя выходной параметр в хранимой процедуре, не стоит забывать про инструкцию SET NOCOUNT ON, которая отключает вывод количества затронутых процедурой строк вместо выходного параметра.